# Como asegurarse que una conexión existe para reconectar un WebSocket

Tags: android, websocket

Desde una aplicación  envió una información, por medio de sockets pero al cerrarse la conexión a internet el Socket se cierra, como puedo levantar nuevamente el socket y así no se detenga la aplicación al hacer el nuevo envió de información.

```
 private void connectWebSocket() {
    URI uri;
    try {
        uri = new URI("ws://192.95.22.177:9300");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
            JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
            try {
                params.put("MESSAGE", "Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONObject datax = new JSONObject();
            try {
                datax.put("CLASS", "ClaseMensajes");
                datax.put("METHOD", "insertMessage");
                datax.put("PARAMS", params);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String jsonStr = datax.toString();
            mWebSocketClient.send(jsonStr);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Closed Pro " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    };
    mWebSocketClient.connect();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero vas a necesitar un *BroadcastReceiver* para supervisar la conexión:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo net = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        boolean isConnected = net!=null && net.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (isConnected) {

            // tu codigo para reconnectar el websocket aqui

            Log.d("Network Available ", "YES");
        } else {
            Log.d("Network Available ", "NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Además tienes que declarar los permisos en el manifesto:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

y finalmente registrar el receiver en tu codigo:

```
    BroadcastReceiver br = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION");
    registerReceiver(br,filter);
```